# Run npm script command in current shell

Tags: npm

I'm using npm run-script feature, and would like to run commands that should effect the current shell.
For example I would like to be able to export variables or source a file.

```
"scripts": {
  "example": "export name=eden && source someVirtualenv/bin/activate",
}
```

It seems that npm automatically creates a sub process, is there a way to make it run on current shell?